# Magento 2 Moving Currency Switcher

Tags: currency

New to Magento 2 and not quite understanding the docs. In child Luma theme I am trying to move the currency switcher to the main header area (next to the minicart) but having no luck with it.

In /app/design/frontend/MyVendor/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/layout I placed the following default.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<move element="currency" destination="header" after="minicart"/>
</page>
```

The switcher disappears from the panel header, but doesn't appear where I expect. I tried various combinations of before and after blocks and tried to move it to different blocks like maincontent, but in all cases I can't get it to show. There are a couple of previous posts from people trying to move the currency switcher but no successful answers so far. Is it possible? Moving it by phtml didn't work at all.

Comment: I think, You need to put `move` into `<body>` tag & put <?xml version="1.0"?> at the starting of xml

Comment: Did that, no change (see answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Correct `xml` should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="currency" destination="header" after="minicart"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Sorry, <?xml version="1.0"?> was in there, I just hadn't pasted it into the question. Anyway, tried the above code and still nothing. I looked at the HTML output, there's not even any wrapping tags there. The block is just not being rendered at all.

Comment: The site in question is at dev.lucemillpack.com. Looking at source code with the above xml in place, currency switcher is no longer in the panel header, but also nowhere else on the page. Changing destination to other blocks makes no difference.

Comment: I have checked and currency switcher is available with `dispaly:none`. please search currency in your html.

Comment: I think that's part of the theme's responsive behaviour: some elements like the account links and currency switcher are actually included twice: once in the panel header and once in the navigation area. On screens above 767px width those elements are hidden from the navigation area with display: none. Below 767px, the panel header is hidden and the account links and currency switcher are shown as tabs in the navigation area. But there is no currency block in the main header area, which is where I would expect it to appear after using the above xml.